# Как перейти на другую страницу с переменной php через код javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, php5

PHP

```
 $url['url'][$i]      = trim($data[3]);
```

java script

```
<script>
    window.location.href = "$url";// ?
</script>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить код

Comment: ну так не массив же нужно подсовывать в href, а строку

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо добавить теги php

```
<script>
    window.location.href = "<?php echo $url; ?>";
</script>
```